# Eclipse, PHP, apache and the localhost (confused about file transfer)

Tags: php, eclipse, localhost

Set up Eclipse, PHP, and Apache. I check out the local host, and I am getting the "it works!".

I am relearning this, and back in the day, I simply uploaded my files via ftp to the server and 'debugged' them, or more specifically, just looked at them in browsers.

I am wondering if it is possible to satisfy this primitive urge to have it automated to install and 'run' my scripts from my localhost, that is from my own computer, just to see, or if I should just give it up and configure Zend debugger.

In other words, is it pointless or impossible to have an Eclipse test project 'uploaded'/written to your file system (default /htdocs) in order to emulate an ftp transfer in order to see how the page looks in browsers?

The feeling I get is I haven't installed/configured something properly that would cover this in a more modern way.

Now I know I could just manually edit and upload the index page and set up the entire file system, but I was hoping for something more integrated with Eclipse. I notice that when creating projects, when attempting to run them I see something like "localhost/[project name]/newfile.php, which makes me wonder.

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Do you mean you want to debug your site locally or that you want to view the system locally?

Comment: May be you are talking about creating a project "eclipse->other->Remote Server Explorer" kind of thing, which can create a project on the remote ftp and will let you edit and files and automatically save there itself. This all can  be done from  your localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my question was unclear. I wanted to develop a .php file in eclipse, then have Eclipse upload it to my server.

I know this seems somewhat backwards a thing to do than to first develop on a local configuration of php/apache, test it first, and then finally deploy it, which may have confused some people. Pardon my ignorance in any case.

But the more specific question (I think) is this:

"How can I use eclipse and ftp to upload files to a web server? Like a built in FileZilla?"

The answer is simple:

1) Right click on your project

2) Select 'Export'

3) Choose 'Remote Systems > Remote file system' and click next.

4) From there, click 'Browse' to choose the remote server.

5) Click 'New' to create a new connection.

6) Click 'FTP Only'

That is it.

One 'problem' I ran into was I forgot the password to my ftp. I tried going through the above steps to see if I could delete or edit, or create a new connection, but none of them worked, and the connection kept on using the wrong credentials.

The solution turns out equally simple; simply go to Window > Show View > Other, then Remote Systems > Remote Systems.

From that view, you can pretty much do whatever you need to do.

Thanks for your patience, you are all gentlemen/ladies and scholars.